# Html button over an image

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

How can have a button or link like the following which stays on top an image? See the red ovals in the image below.

I have got this image from [carousel](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp) and tweaked the style a bit like this.

```
<style>
.carousel-inner > .item > img,
.carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}
</style>
```

I made the width =100% so that the buttons are now on the images rather than outside.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want something like this 
Site point has very good and simple article that answers your question with the title.

**How to Make a Simple Image Slider With HTML, CSS and jQuery**
Follow this [link](https://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/making-simple-image-slider-html-css-jquery/)

Hope this link is helpful to you

Comment: Helpful but not exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
.carousel-inner{position:relative;}
.carousel-inner > .item > a{position:absolute; top:50%; margin-top:-20px; display:block;}
.carousel-inner > .item > a.prev{left:20px;}
.carousel-inner > .item > a.next{right:20px;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use position:absolute for buttons or links in your css file.